# Looking for formula to add "bullet pointers" at the beggining of every sentence within a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to insert bullet pointers at the beginning of every line within the same cell. Is there a formula or a macro to do so?

Below are line items that would be present within a single cell, where i would need a bullet point at the beginning of every sentence:-

*Waterproof membrane seals out water and lets moisture escape

Suede leather and mesh upper

Traditional lace closure

Bellows tongue keeps out debris

Protective rubber toe cap for durability and protection

Breathable mesh lining

Kinetic Fit™ BASE removable contoured insole for flexible support

Molded nylon arch shank

Air Cushion in the heel absorbs shock and adds stability

Lightweight EVA foam midsole for stability and comfort*

I would like the end result to look like below:-

[image]

Appreciate the help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use SUBSTITUTE to replace all the line returns with line returns and the bullet:

```
=CHAR(149)&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(10)&CHAR(149))
```

[image]

Make sure you have wrap text turned on for the output cell.

Comment: This is brilliant. I worked. Thank you @scott Craner. Much appreciated

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer